# I can't migrate on heroku. Using Django MySQL

Tags: python, django, heroku

I can't migrate on Heroku. Using Django and MySQL.
I don't what wrong with it.
There are some wrongs on setting_mysql.py?

I got an error like this.

```
(base) mypc@mypc website % heroku run python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ myapp... up, run.3308 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have provided the wrong database access credentials, because if I'm not mistaken - you can't connect to the database via socket.

Try official solution:

> On Heroku, sensitive credentials are stored in the environment as
> config vars. This includes database connection information (named
> DATABASE_URL), which is traditionally hardcoded in Django
> applications.
>
> The django-heroku package automatically configures your Django
> application to work on Heroku. It is compatible with Django 2.0
> applications.
>
> It provides many niceties, including the reading of DATABASE_URL,
> logging configuration, a Heroku CI–compatible TestRunner, and
> automatically configures ‘staticfiles’ to “just work”.
>
> Installing django-heroku:
>
> `pip install django-heroku`
>
> Be sure to add django-heroku to your requirements.txt file as well.
>
> Add the following import statement to the top of `settings.py`:
>
> `import django_heroku`
>
> Then add the following to the bottom of settings.py:
>
> Activate Django-Heroku:
> `django_heroku.settings(locals())`
>
> Deploy, and you should be good to go!

I'm using this solution and it works for me.
Another option is to copy the database access data in the database panel and manually put it into settings.py

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it. I changed "DATABASES" section settings.py for Heroku and now it works!